# Automatic shutdown of Azure VMSS instance by low CPU workload

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, azure-vm-scale-set, runbook

I'd like to automatic shutdown by low CPU usage condition.
I didn't find any info around VMSS instance.

Comment: You want to shutdown all instances when low CPU or shutdown one instance?

Comment: If you only want to shutdown one instance, you could select scale down one instance, no need shutdown it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is autoscale (probably). It would add\remove VMSS instances on demand. It is easy to setup. Just follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-overview#set-up-scaling-using-the-azure-portal) article to get the links to how to set it up using different methods. To add to those methods you can also use ARM Template.

Answer (score 1):

You can create scaling rule and define if you want to decrease by count or percentage,
[Scaling-in Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZEbJ.png)
I'm guessing the purpose of this need is the economic reason then maybe checking low priority VMSS helps you reduce cost by another method
[VMSS low priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-use-low-priority)
[Azure Friday VMSS low priority](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-low-priority-vm-scale-set-vmss/)